# Difference in linq-to-sql query performance using GenericRespositry

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Given i have a class like so in my *Data Layer*

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class 
{

   public MyDataContext DataContext {get;set;}

   [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethod(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
   public IQueryable<TEntity> SelectAll()
   {
      return DataContext.GetTable<TEntity>();
   }
}
```

I would be able to query a table in my database like so from a *higher layer*

```
using (GenericRepositry<MyTable> mytable = new GenericRepositry<MyTable>())
{
   var myresult = from m in mytable.SelectAll()
                  where m.IsActive
                  select m;
}
```

is this considerably slower than using the usual code in my *Data Layer*

```
using (MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
   var myresult = from m in ctx.MyTable
                  where m.IsActive
                  select m;
}
```

Eliminating the need to write simple single table selects in the Data layer saves a lot of time, but will i regret it?

Edit: @ Skeet
I have actually implemented this approach in a fairly large WCF/Silverlight LOB project, and it seems our servers CPU's are struggling to keep up. The extra work of creating/destroying extra objects couldn't possibly be attributed to the rise in cpu usage over projects using the usual way?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so... but profile it to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown where your "generic repository" is getting its context from - I assume it's creating a new one, and proxying the dispose call?

If so, it should basically be the same - it's been a while since I looked into the difference between `GetTable<T>()` and using the property, but I wouldn't be surprised if the property just called `GetTable<T>` itself. Other than that, there's no real difference.

The important point is that you're still using `IQueryable<T>` in both cases, so the query will still be translated into SQL - if your `SelectAll` method returned `IEnumerable<T>` instead, it would be disastrous.

Comment: can you please throw lights on the last line?

Comment: @Veer: If the method returned `IEnumerable<T>`, the query expression would be using LINQ to Objects, doing filtering etc in process instead of in SQL.